# Azure Active Directory - export list of users together with nested groups by powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I have a group in Azure Active Directory, which have nested groups. I would like to export list of users, together with their groups b running powershell script.
Ideally I'd like output to show user's name, email and group.
I tried writing a script but I am able to only list groups or only names, but not everything together..

At the moment I have the below code, but I don't know why I keep getting error:
Get-AzureADGroupMember : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null.

```
$groups=Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString 'my-group-name'
$resultsarray =@()
ForEach ($group in $groups)
{
$members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId

 #Recursive call if the object is a group
        if ($members.ObjectType -eq 'Group')
        {
                  $resultarray += Get-AzureADGroupMembers -ObjectId $member.ObjectId
        }
}

#Add to output if object is a user
        if ($members.ObjectType -eq 'User')
        {
                   ForEach ($member in $members){
       $UserObject = new-object PSObject
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Group Name" -Value $group.DisplayName
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Member Name" -Value $member.DisplayName
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "ObjType" -Value $member.ObjectType
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserType" -Value $member.UserType
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserPrinicpalName" -Value $member.UserPrincipalName
       $resultsarray += $UserObject
    }
          }
    $resultsarray | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8  -Delimiter ";" -Path 'C:\Users\Desktop\aadgroupmembers.csv'
```

Comment: I tested you code and everything works on my end.  The only thing I can think of that would cause a null error is if the group you are searching for does not exist.

Which get Get-AzureADGroupMembers command is giving you the null error?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. This is the full error: 
Get-AzureADGroupMember : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null.
At line:5 char:47
+    $group = (Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupId -All $True| Se ...
+                                               ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-AzureADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetGroupMembers

Answer (score 3):

I created an **Azure AD Group and added members** like below:

[image]

And in the nested group **`rukgroup`**, added members like below:

[image]

To fetch the **list of users together with nested groups**, make use of below PowerShell script:

```bash
$group = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "testnestedgrp"

$resultsarray = @()

$members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true

foreach ($member in $members) {
    if ($member.ObjectType -eq "User") {
        $user = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $member.ObjectId
        $userObject = New-Object PSObject
        $userObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "GroupName" -Value $group.DisplayName
        $userObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MemberName" -Value $user.DisplayName
        $userObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UPN" -Value $user.UserPrincipalName
        $userObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NestedGroupName" -Value $null
        $resultsarray += $userObject
    }
    else {
        if ($member.ObjectType -eq "Group") {
            $nestedGroup = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $member.ObjectId
            $nestedGroupObject = New-Object PSObject
            $nestedGroupObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "GroupName" -Value $group.DisplayName
            $nestedGroupObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NestedGroupName" -Value $nestedGroup.DisplayName
            $nestedGroupObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MemberName" -Value $null
            $nestedGroupObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UPN" -Value $null
            $resultsarray += $nestedGroupObject

          
            $nestedMembers = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $nestedGroup.ObjectId -All $true
            foreach ($nestedMember in $nestedMembers) {
                if ($nestedMember.ObjectType -eq "User") {
                    $nestedUser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $nestedMember.ObjectId
                    $nestedUserObject = New-Object PSObject
                    $nestedUserObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "GroupName" -Value $group.DisplayName
                    $nestedUserObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NestedGroupName" -Value $nestedGroup.DisplayName
                    $nestedUserObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MemberName" -Value $nestedUser.DisplayName
                    $nestedUserObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UPN" -Value $nestedUser.UserPrincipalName
                    $resultsarray += $nestedUserObject
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host "Object not found: $($nestedMember.ObjectType)"
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Object not found: $($member.ObjectType)"
        }
    }
}

$resultsarray | Export-Csv -Path "C:\aadgroupmembers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

**The CSV file got exported successfully with the nested group name with members like below:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Rukmini thank you for your input and sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately this didn't work for my case, I think it is because inside nested groups I have more nested groups.. It looks like your code returned the first layer of nested groups. Structure in my group is somehow like this: Main Group -> Second Group  -> Third Group. And there may be several Second and Third Groups..